# Remove additional PCR timestamps from mpg file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg, gop

I'm trying to produce a video file output keeping a constant PCR period of 95 ms, currently i have this command (I removed some parameters to make it easier to read):

```
ffmpeg -i $SRC_FILE -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -f mpegts -pcr_period 95 -r 23.976 -g 12 -x264-params:v keyint=12:min-keyint=12 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*0.5)" $TARGET_FILE
```

The problem i have is that often i get 95 ms gaps betweem PCR timestamps, but I keep getting smaller gaps, for example these are the values of the gaps between PCRs in miliseconds for a random chunk of the video file:

> 95, 14, 81, 95, 95, 95, 95, 39, 56, 95, 95, 95, 95, 69, 26, 95

Whilst most of these values are ok i would like them to be more accurate.

The only solution that seems to work so far is increasing the GOP value, if i set as the -g and keyint/min_keyint parameters a high value like 300 instead of 12 i get much more constant gaps. (over 95% accuracy)

I'm not sure if ffmpeg is just adding PCR timestamp values to every keyframe and this is why for low GOP values the gaps are reduced.

I can't either reduce the PCR period or increase the GOP value due to hardware constraints, is there anything it can be done with ffmpeg to prevent additional PCR values from being added? or is there any other tool that can be used for this purpose?